# Next.JS <Script> tag in Next.js page not executing JavaScript function on page load

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to run a script in my Next.js application and am confused as to why the script is not executing when my page is loaded. I am not sure if my syntax is incorrect in using the Next.js  tags or if somehow I have the wrong path for my Javascript function. Could anyone help direct me toward the solution?

Here is the section of code that I have in question (the script tag is the last line)

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Script from 'next/script';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
   return (
      <>
      <Script src="./js/main.js"/>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.  Also explain better what " not running properly" means. See [ask].

Comment: Did you check main.js is being loaded on the devtools -> Network Tab?

Comment: For instance, check the network tab in the devtools to see if you're getting a 4xx or 5xx response for that asset.